# Label over button, how to highlight text on button press in iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton, uilabel

I have a button and multiple labels placed over the button in storyboard. For the button I specified a default and a highlight state. Also for the labels I specified the highlight color in storyboard.

However on button press the font color of the label does not change to white. Am I missing something? I would like to configure this behavior in storyboard, not programmatically. Is this possible? Or do I have to create a custom button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `UILabel` **does not** get the touch events because it simply **does not** handle touch events by design, it's just for showing text.

You might want to create a subclass of a `UIButton` but this is not a good idea since it's kind of a cluster class.

Best way to do it is creating a custom button class by subclassing either `UIControl` or `UIView`. With the later you could add it in your storyboard by changing their class to one of your button subclasses. In the subclass make your customizations in the `initWithCoder:` method.

If you decided to choose the `UIControl` way of doing this. Look at `setHighlighted:` method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted: highlighted];
    // Highlight your labels here
}
```

Useful link: [UIControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html)